# Pre-populating a Spring MVC form

Tags: forms, spring-mvc, session-variables

I am looking for a way to **pre-populate a Spring MVC form** from values stored in a session-scoped bean. (using this namespace: http://www.springframework.org/tags/form).

For example, say I have added a **queryInfo** object to the **uiModel**.

How do I display the **name** instance variable from the **queryInfo** object?

```
<form:input path="queryInfo.name" />
```

Is this possible? If so how?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your request mapping, add the bean to the model:

```
model.addAttribute("queryInfo", queryInfo);
```

Then use modelAttribute in the form tag to bind it to the form:

```
<form:form id="some-form" modelAttribute="queryInfo">

...
```

Now name will display (provided there is a getter in your object appropriately named) when you do this:

```
<form:input path="name" />
```

Keep in mind form:input is a child tag of form:form.  It is not meant to be used on its own.

Answer (score 0):

@skel625's solution for form:input is perfect, but in the case of the form:select, with different option how do I set attributes? because in this way only works for the form:input

My form:select is like this:

```
<form:select path="dolorefastidio">
                        <option value="1"><spring:message code="questionnaire.compile.label.paindiscomfort.one"/></option>
                        <option value="2"><spring:message code="questionnaire.compile.label.paindiscomfort.two"/></option>
                        <option value="3"><spring:message code="questionnaire.compile.label.paindiscomfort.three"/></option>
                        <option value="4"><spring:message code="questionnaire.compile.label.paindiscomfort.four"/></option>
                        <option value="5"><spring:message code="questionnaire.compile.label.paindiscomfort.five"/></option>
                    </form:select>
```

Answer (score 0):

> the solution is put in a value attribute the bean attribute like this

Exam Register Form

```
                    <div class="form-group has-success">
                        <label for="code" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Exam Code</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-9">
                            <form:input type="text" class="form-control" path="cod" placeholder="code" value="${editExam.cod}"/>                        
                            <form:errors path="cod" cssClass="error" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group has-success">
                        <label for="name" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Exam Name</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-9">
                            <form:input type="text" class="form-control" path="name" placeholder="name" value="${editExam.name}"/>
                            <form:errors path="name" cssClass="error" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group has-success">
                        <label for="teachNme" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Teacher Name</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-9">
                            <form:input type="text" class="form-control" path="teachName"
                                placeholder="Teacher Name" value="${exams.teachName}"  />
                            <form:errors path="teachName" cssClass="error" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group has-success">
                        <label for="vote" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Final Grade</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-9">
                            <form:input type="text" class="form-control" path="vote"
                                placeholder="Vote" value="${exams.vote}"  />
                            <form:errors path="vote" cssClass="error" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group has-success">
                        <label for="cfu" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Credits (CFU)</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-9">
                            <form:input type="text" class="form-control" path="cfu"
                                placeholder="Credits" value="${editExam.cfu}"  />
                            <form:errors path="cfu" cssClass="error" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Save"
                        class="btn btn-primary pull-right">
                </fieldset>
            </form:form>
```